# Using cursor Adapter to get songs in a list view

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I want to get song titles from media store to a list view can someone explain me whats wrong in the code ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Cursor cursour;
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cur, new String[] {
                "MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI"
            },
            new int[] {
                android.R.id.text1
            }, 0);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songlist);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get songs into list view

```
public void getAudioList() {
    String orderBy = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE ;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID }, selection, null, orderBy);

    int count = mCursor.getCount();
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        mSongsList.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
        SongsPath.add(mCursor.getLong(mCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)));
    }
    mCursor.close();
}

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    getAudioList();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mSongsList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```